# Why is a bright reindeer shown when Harry Potter was saving himself and Sirius Black from the Dementors?

Tags: harry-potter, the-prisoner-of-azkaban

In "Harry Potter and The Prisoner of Azkaban", if Harry (who time travelled) was protecting himself and Sirius Black from the Dementors then why a **bright magical reindeer** like image is shown on the other side of the lake?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It was not a **reindeer** but a **stag**. Harry Potter's Patronus is a stag. Harry and Hermione travel back in time to when they were standing on the other side of the lake.  Future-Harry sees that Dementors are sucking the souls of Harry and Sirius and casts the Patronus. This Patronus is in the form of a stag. Hence Past-Harry sees a stag on other side of the lake.

[image]

Comment: but after this scene,harry was shown on the other side of the lake and using his wand. Then how his patronus came to their rescue?

Comment: and why the same stag was not there when harry came after time travelling?

Comment: Because the stag for created by Harry after time travell.

Comment: Because he was standing right behind it or at the place where the stag is. In the movie they have not shown a stag when harry casts the patronous but in the book it is explained well.

Comment: don't worry if it was confusing, because the movie didn't do a good job of explaining this at all. it's quite sad that one of the best and most important parts of the book (explaining who moony, wormtail, padfoot, and prongs are) didn't make it into the film.

Comment: @sgroves I agree

Comment: A Stag is a male deer. Male Reindeers... ***are Stags...***

Comment: @cde Female reindeers have antlers too. **Plot twist**: Harry's Patronus is not a stag after all, but a reindeer doe!

Comment: @sgroves - honestly, it's extremely clear what is happening in the movie. I can't imagine how someone got confused by this, would their head explode after watching the Matrix?

Comment: @Davor well, I got four upvotes, so clearly I'm not the only one. There was no explanation whatsoever WHY his patronus is a stag. *This is a key part of the story!* It's because they left out the entire explanation of who the Marauders were. It ruined the movie for me.

Answer (score 14):

It was Harry potter's [Patronus](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Patronus_Charm). He creates the Patronus for protection from the Dementors.

After future Harry came from time travel, he realized during the process that he has to save himself, he created the Patronus to help it past form.

From chapter 21 in [wikia](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Harry_Potter_and_the_Prisoner_of_Azkaban)

> After two hours, following Lupin's transformation, Harry decides they need to head back to Hagrid's empty cabin so Lupin doesn't attack them. After spending some time in hiding, Harry leaves the cabin to check out the present situation and sees himself, Hermione, and Black fainting from Dementors. He realises that the silver stag he saw earlier across the lake was not cast by his dad and conjures a powerful Patronus that drives all the Dementors away. When it returns to him, he pets it and realises that it was the same patronus as "Prongs," his father.